# How to help Unity3d engine to find JDK installed on my Linux machine?

Tags: java, android, linux, unity-game-engine

I'm developing on Unity3d 5.2 a game which should be build for an Android. I use Ubuntu 14.04.

I used:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7jdk
```

to install java.
Set $JAVA_HOME and $PATH variables in .bashrc like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin
```

Executed .bashrc:

```
source .bashrc
```

When I check system vars with:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
echo $PATH
```

it gives me:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin
```

I have installed android-sdk. 
But still when I try to build for android in Unity it shows choose folder window, I choose my jdk installation but it gives me error:

*"The path you specified does not look like a valid JDK installation. Android development requires at least JDK 7 (1.7), having JRE only is not enough..."*

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? Please, help!

Comment: Did you solve it ?

Comment: Well, I had to install java under wine for windows, not one for linux.